# pytest takes 10 minutes to collect at builtins compile method

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

i have a pytest test suite with about 1800 tests which takes more than 10 minutes to collect and execute. i tried to create a cprofile on the test and found out that majority of the time, around 300 seconds went in `{built-in method builtins.compile}`
There were some other compile method calls from the regular expression package which i tried to remove and saw a reduction of about 50 seconds. but it still takes 9.5 minutes which is huge.

What i understood till now is that the builtins compile method is used to convert the script into code object and that pytest internally uses this function for creating and executing code objects. But 9-10 minutes is insanely huge amount of time for running 1800 tests. I am new to pytest and python so trying to figure out the reason for this time.

Could there be a possibility that pytest is not configured properly that it uses compile method to generate code object ? or could the other imported libraries use compile internally ?

Answer (score 1):

> Could there be a possibility that pytest is not configured properly that it uses compile method to generate code object ?

Though I have never looked, I would fully expect pytest to `compile` files to bytecode by hand, for the simple reason that [it performs assertion rewriting by default in order to instrument `assert` statements](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html): when an assertion fails, rather than *just* show the assertion message pytest shows the various intermediate values. This requires compiling either way: either they're compiling the code to bytecode and rewriting the bytecode, or they're parsing the code to the AST, updating the AST, and still compiling to bytecode.

It's possible to disable this behaviour (`--assert=plain`), but I would not expect there to be much gain from it (though I could be wrong): pytest simply does that instead of the interpreter performing the compilation on its own. It has to be done one way or an other for the test suite to run.

Though taking 5 minutes does sound like a lot, do you have a large amounts of very small files or something? Rough benching indicates that `compile` works at about 5usec/line on my machine (though it probably depends on code complexity). I've got 6kLOC worth of test, and while the test suite takes ages it's because the tests themselves are expensive, the collection is unnoticeable.

Of course it's possible you could be triggering some sort of edge case or issue in pytest e.g. maybe you have an ungodly number of `assert` statements which causes pytest to generate an insane amount of rewritten code? The aforementioned `--assert=plain` could hint at that if it makes running the test suite *significantly* shorter.

You could also try running e.g. `--collect-only` to see what that yields, though I don't know whether the assertion rewriting is performed during or after the collection. FWIW on the 6kLOC test suite above I get 216 tests collected in 1.32s.

Either way this seems like something more suitable to the pytest bug tracker.

> or could the other imported libraries use compile internally ?

You could use a flamegraph-based profiler to record the entire stack. cprofile is, frankly, kinda shit.